# Want to identify serverside exception in javascript from jquery ajax return

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to identify there was an exception and show in the page somehow, by using ajax through JQuery it doesnt show anything ( of couse, cuz I didn't develop it )

the point is, what is the faster way of doing it?   I don't want to up one level on my entity in order to create an "IsError" field... not a chance, neither I want to set status code error to handle it on the ui side,  just want to identify it as an exception in the javascript ajax return side and manage it any direction I want.

```
      function PostSomething() {
            var someData = "name=joe";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/SomeController/SomeAction/',
                data: someData,
                success: function (msg) {
                    for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                        $('#someCombo').append(new Option(msg[i].TheName, msg[i].ID, false, true));
                    }
                    $("#someCombo").focus();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Jquery ajax has an error callback method, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `error` property.

```
  function PostSomething() {
        var someData = "name=joe";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/SomeController/SomeAction/',
            data: someData,
            success: function (msg) {
                for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                    $('#someCombo').append(new Option(msg[i].TheName, msg[i].ID, false, true));
                }
                $("#someCombo").focus();
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('something is wrong'); 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks but how would error callback identify the server exceptio as an error?

Comment: @EdwinSnts see my solution, you can do different things to handle different statuscodes by specifying the statusCode property

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a certain status code... say a 404 or 500, you could handle them differently...

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(){
    alert("it worked");
  },
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert("page not found");
    },
    500: function() {
      alert("server error");
    }
  }
});
```